# Why I get all None in my list after permutation?

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, numpy, permutation

I have a list `x = [['a', 'b', 'c'], ['d'], ['e', 'f', ['g', ['h', 'i']]]]`
I want to do all possible permutations of elements in sublists without going beyond corresponding sublist.
I use this generator:

```
import numpy as np
def ff(x):
    if isinstance(x, list) == True:
        res = np.random.choice(x, len(x), replace = False)
        return [list(map(ff, res))]

    else:
        print(x)
```

But however when i do

```
ff(x)
```

I get something like this:

```
[[[[None]], [[None, None, None]], [[[[None, [[None, None]]]], None, None]]]]
```

Could you tell me please where i made a mistake?
The expected output are variations of something like this:

```
[['c', 'b', 'a'], ['d'], ['f', 'e', ['g', ['i', 'h']]]]
[['d'], ['a', 'b', 'c'], ['f', 'e', [['h', 'i'], 'g']]]
```

As you see each element is kept in it's square bracket. I need it for tree leafs permutations.

Comment: You want to `return x`, not `print(x)`.

Comment: Can you update your question to include expected output? If you have to, show us expected output for a simpler input. This will help clarify your question and get a quick answer :D

Comment: @sanyash yeah that's it, thanks, im so inattentive sometimes)

Comment: Just a suggestion: if isinstance(x, list): is sufficient, == True is not needed and generally not recommended